# Error while passing the SQL query in asp using parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using this code and while I run my code I got an error.

> Incorrect Syntax near where clause.

This is my C# code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ANURAG-PC;Initial Catalog=dbPortal;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=yyyy;Password=xxxxx");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if (IsPostBack == false)
   {
       string s = Request.QueryString["cat"];
       string s1 = Request.QueryString["sub"];

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Architect where where SubCategory1 = @sub1",con);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub1", s1);

       con.Open();

       using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           DataTable dat = new DataTable("tab");
           dat.Load(reader);
           DataGrid1.DataSource = dat;
           DataGrid1.DataBind();
       }
    }
}
```

Whats wrong in it?

Comment: In the future, take care not to post the login details to the SQL Server in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the query - you have `where where` there. There should only be one `where`:

```
SqlCommand cmd = 
    new SqlCommand("Select * from Architect where where SubCategory1=@sub1",con);
```

Should be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = 
    new SqlCommand("Select * from Architect where SubCategory1=@sub1",con);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello correct delete where, you have two where

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Architect where where SubCategory1=@sub1",con);

-> SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Architect where SubCategory1=@sub1",con);
```